# What does an instruction return in C?

Tags: c

I would like to know what does this expression test:

```
if ((a=b)!=0)
```

Is it equivalent to `(if (a!=0))`?

Comment: It is equivalent to "compiler error". Make sure to post *valid* code, unless the issue really is about a compiler error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
if ((a=b))!=0)
```

its `error`

it should be

```
if ((a=b)!=0))
```

if both a=b=`some same integer`

then

it checks whether both `a` and `b` is `not zero`

**OR :**

your intension may be this :

```
a=b;
if(a!=0)
```

Comment: well sorry, the code was: while ((byte = read(fd,buf, length))!=0), what is the purpose of this test?

Comment: Both `((a=b))!=0)` and `((a=b)!=0))` have mismatched parentheses, they both won't compile.

Comment: @user2627156 That statement should have been the one in your question!

Answer (score 3):

When used as an operator, `=` both assigns the value from the right side to the variable on the left side and returns the new value of that variable (for example, if `a` is an integer value, `(a=3.4)` returns 3). So this is equivalent to:

```
a=b;
if(a!=0)
```

Comment: Not quite. Assignment **converts** the value on the right side to the type of the left side, assigns that value to the object on the left side, and returns the **converted** value. E.g., given `int x`, the value of `x = 3.5` is 3, not 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

```
Almost everything in C return values.An expression like `a=b` also returns value.
```

What is happening in the code

```
if ((a=b)!=0)) // By the way what you posted wont compile...
```

is value of b is assigned to a and that value is again checked where it is not equal to `0`
It is similar to

```
a = b;
if(a!=0)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not quite. Assignment **converts** the value on the right side to the type of the left side, assigns that value to the object on the left side, and returns the **converted** value. E.g., given `int x`, the value of `x = 3.5` is 3, not 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

If a and b are equal then you need not assign it as a=b inside if condition. Assign a=b outside if condition and then check if a!=0

Answer (score 0):

there is an extra ) in ur code it should be if((a=b) != 0)

First a = b is evaluated i.e value of b will be in a.

second the result of the operation will be evaluated with != 0

(i.e result of the expression is value of a).

which is equal to

```
      if (a!=0)
```

if u assign the value of b to a before comparison

```
         b = a;
         if (a!=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Expression is Invalid, the valid one will have one lesser closing bracket

```
if ((a=b)!=0)
```

this code is equivalent to if(b!=0).

Comment: yes a will have same value as of b hence the expression is equivalent to if(b!=0)

Comment: No. It's equivalent to the two statements `a = b` then `if(b != 0)`.

Comment: @Quirliom No, it's equivalent to the two statements `a = b;` and then `if (a != 0)`. An implicit conversion from `b`'s type to `a`'s type may turn a non-zero value into zero.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your question, for example, you're asking about "the expression"

```
if ((a=b)!=0)
```

and also about the expression

```
(if (a!=0))
```

In C, such things are not expressions. Loosely as such, they're errors. So it'd be better if you had this code in context. Those parenthesis enclosing the second if, though, are very likely to be wrong.

Another issue with your question is that you may be thinking C has conditional if expressions like haskell, scheme, SML, closure, and so forth. I don't think this is the issue you're talking about, but if it's, then you should look at the `?:` operator.

In the case you're asking about the conditional expressions used in the two if statements, then they're not equivalent. Performing `(a=b)!=0` is different from performing `a!=0`. The first one assigns the value of `b` to `a` and compares the newly assigned value of `a` to 0 in order to see if they're different. The second one just compares the value of `a` with 0 to see if they're different, without assigning it to `b` beforehand.